# Regex to replace spaces after specific word found on any line across multiple files

Tags: regex, sublime-text

I am using Sublime Text, and I was wondering if there is a way to do this with Regex:

I have multiple files that have different lines and text.

In each of them I have a line that starts with "NAME : " and continues with the name of the person:

```
NAME : john doe smith
```

I am looking to use Regex to replace the spaces found in the text `john doe smith` with a character `_`, basically after the text `NAME :` , so the new line will be:

```
NAME : john_doe_smith
```

So far I have tried doing this: Matching the line that contains "NAME" (couldn't get it working with the full one "NAME : ") with Find:

```
^.*\b(NAME)\b.*$
```

But I don't know how to replace the spaces after the match.

Is there a way to accomplish this with Regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your regex flavour, you can do:

- Find: `(?:^NAME : |\G(?!^))\w+\K\h`
- Replace: `_`

A demo and explanation can be [found here on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oP9U37/1).

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked flawlessly! this is amazing, thanks a lot! I've been looking for a solution for a while, this is a life saver, thank you!

Comment: @Lernisios: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: As with my comment below, would there be a Regex syntax I can use to also make all the characters that are found after "NAME : " as lowercase?

I do like the sed command, but looking to use regex as well.

thank you!

Comment: I tried this that will convert the titlecase at the beginning of each word to lower case Find `(\w+) (\w+) (\w+) (\w+)` and then Replace with `\L$1 $2 $3 $4` , but did not find a way to replace all characters inside a word

Comment: If your regex flavour supports conditonnal replacement, you can use Find: `(?:^NAME : |\G(?!^))\K(\w+)(\h)?` Replace: `\L$1(?2_:)` If it doesn't, you have to do the job in 2 psteps 1) the regx I gave in answer 2) Find `^NAME : \K.+` Replace: `\L$0`. Edit your question and add tag for which program/tool you're using.

Comment: thanks for the help @Toto ! I added in the question what tool I am using - Sublime Text. I've tried the first one you mentioned, and it did not work well.

But then I tried the 2nd one Find `^NAME : \K.+` Replace: `\L$0` and it worked beautifully! also it works if I have title case letters inside an word, not just at the beginning of the word. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you're using the regex:

The following uses sed:

```
sed ':redo s/^\(\s*NAME\s*:\s*\S\+\)\s\+\([^_[:space:]]\)/\1_\2/ ;t redo' files
```

The trick here is the `t redo`, which does a conditional branch back to the label redo, to rerun the replacement until it fails.

Note that the pattern includes some glue to make spaces around the `:` optional, ignore trailing white space and reduce multiple spaces to a single `_`.

Comment: thanks for the help @Giacomo1968

I haven't used sed before, thus I tried it just now; I saw in my command line on Linux Mint that the sed command gives me the preview output, but it does not change the file itself.

This is the command I ran:

`sed ':redo s/^\(\s*NAME\s*:\s*\S\+\)\s\+\([^_[:space:]]\)/\1_\2/ ;t redo' file1.txt`

Is there an extra argument to the sed command that could modify the files themselves, i.e. replace the empty spaces with _ inside the files?

Also, would it be possible for me to make all the characters found after "NAME : " as like lowercase?

Comment: So if my input text is `NAME : John Doe Smith`, then the final output would look like this:
`NAME : john_doe_smith`

PS: I also tried your command to work for all the files in my folder this way, so that it applies to all txt files:
`sed ':redo s/^\(\s*NAME\s*:\s*\S\+\)\s\+\([^_[:space:]]\)/\1_\2/ ;t redo' *.txt`

Comment: @Lernisios I only edited the answer. _darkonc_ is the one who posted the answer so they would be the ones to answer these follow up comments!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 thanks!

Comment: @darkonc would greatly appreciate your help on this, thanks!

Comment: the option -i  or --in-place will edit the files.

Comment: 'man sed'  on the command line for more info on sed . man pages are your friend on UNIX if you haven't used them before.  'info sed'

Comment: To convert everything after the "NAME : " to lower case, add a second edit.   

    `s/^\(\sNAME\s:\s*\)\(.*\)/\1\L\2/`
...  so the full line would be:    

    `sed ':redo s/^\(\s*NAME\s*:\s*\S\+\)\s\+\([^_[:space:]]\)/\1_\2/ ;t redo ; s/^\(\sNAME\s:\s*\)\(.*\)/\1\L\2/ ' *.txt`
... add  -i  for an in-file edit

Comment: thanks a lot @darkonc !!! it worked great !!! I ran this command and added the option -i to edit the files `sed -i ':redo s/^\(\s*NAME\s*:\s*\S\+\)\s\+\([^_[:space:]]\)/\1_\2/ ;t redo ; s/^\(\sNAME\s:\s*\)\(.*\)/\1\L\2/ ' *.txt`

Just wanted to check that I got it right, the "_" is the one found in the command; so if I want for instance to change it to another character like "~", then I could use this command where I replaced the "-" with "~", is that correct? `sed -i ':redo s/^\(\s*NAME\s*:\s*\S\+\)\s\+\([^~[:space:]]\)/\1~\2/ ;t redo ; s/^\(\sNAME\s:\s*\)\(.*\)/\1\L\2/ ' *.txt"`

Comment: Yes.  You seem to understand it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @darkonc, greatly appreciated!